# Convert Row values into Column values using Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Convert concatenate column and row values and assigned to New column after groupby one column in the  dataframe.

The below code trying to convert the expected results however it taking longer time to run the results.

code:

```
groups = df.groupby("row_number")
df_new = groups.apply(func).droplevel(0)


def func(g: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    first_row_of_group = g.iloc[0]
    g = g.iloc[1:, :]
    cols = range(1, len(first_row_of_group))

    for i in cols:
        g["structure_data"] = (
                g["structure_data"]
                + str(first_row_of_group.iloc[i])
                + "="
                + g.iloc[:, i].apply(try_round)
                + ";"
        )

    return g
```

**DataFrame:**

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | structure_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0D | 1D | 7D | 14D | None |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | None |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | None |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | None |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | None |

**Expected Value in structure_data column:**

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | structure_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | 0D=0.03891;1D=0.0410;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435 |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | 0D=0.03891;1D=0.0410;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435 |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | 0D=0.03891;1D=0.0410;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435 |
| A | 0.03891 | 0.0410 | 0.0417 | 0.0435 | 0D=0.03891;1D=0.0410;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435 |

Answer (score 0):

If you have this dataframe:

```py
  Column A Column B Column C Column D Column E  structure_data
0        A       0D       1D       7D      14D             NaN
1        A  0.03891   0.0411   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
2        A  0.03891   0.0412   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
3        A  0.03891   0.0413   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
4        A  0.03891   0.0414   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
5        B       0D       1D       7D      14D             NaN
6        B  0.03891   0.0415   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
7        B  0.03891   0.0416   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
8        B  0.03891   0.0417   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
9        B  0.03891   0.0418   0.0417   0.0435             NaN
```

Then you can try:

```py
def fn(g):
    r = g.iloc[0]
    g = g.iloc[1:].copy()
    g["structure_data"] = g.apply(
        lambda x: ";".join("=".join(map(str, t)) for t in zip(r[:-1], x[:-1])), axis=1
    )
    return g


out = df.groupby("Column A").apply(fn, include_groups=False).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
  Column A Column B Column C Column D Column E                             structure_data
0        A  0.03891   0.0411   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0411;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
1        A  0.03891   0.0412   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0412;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
2        A  0.03891   0.0413   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0413;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
3        A  0.03891   0.0414   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0414;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
4        B  0.03891   0.0415   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0415;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
5        B  0.03891   0.0416   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0416;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
6        B  0.03891   0.0417   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0417;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
7        B  0.03891   0.0418   0.0417   0.0435  0D=0.03891;1D=0.0418;7D=0.0417;14D=0.0435
```

Comment: Hi Kesely, Thanks for you help, but i'm getting below error for this code.     g["term_structure"] = g.apply(lambda x: ";".join("=".join(t) for t in zip(r[11:-1], x[11:-1])), axis=1)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.   Can we apply the rounding of x value before join?                                  for i in cols:
        g["term_structure"] = (
                g["term_structure"]
                + str(first_row_of_group.iloc[i])
                + "="
                + **g.iloc[:, i].apply(try_round)**
                + ";"
        )